# Local sections of Hopf fibration $(S^3,\pi,S^2)$

Tags: differential-geometry, fiber-bundles, principal-bundles

In the lecture we showed the local triviality of the Hopf fibration $(S^3,\pi,S^2)$ as a principal-$S^1$-bundle by constructing local sections
$$s_1:S^2\setminus\{\infty\}\cong\mathbb{C}\to S^3,\qquad s_1(z):=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\lvert z\rvert^2}}\left(z,1\right)$$ and $$s_2:S^2\setminus\{0\}\to S^3,\qquad s_2(z):=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\lvert z\rvert^2}}(\lvert z\rvert,\lvert z\rvert).$$
At least that is what I have written in my notes, but in general $s_2(z)\notin S^3$. So, what is a correct section $s_2$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We want $s_{1}$ and $s_{2}$ to be compatible with each other under "inversion," i.e. $z\mapsto 1/z$, so the right formula for $s_{2}(z)$ would be just $s_{1}(1/z)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+|z|^{2}}}(\frac{|z|}{z},|z|)$.

Comment: I am not familiar with that compatibility condition. Could you elaborate that further, please?

Comment: Well, I don't know how those local sections are used later in the lecture, but if one section is defined over $S^{2}\backslash\lbrace\infty\rbrace$ and another is defined over $S^{2}\backslash\lbrace0\rbrace$ then naturally we want the two sections to be similar to each other. And the most natural way to converting one domain to another is by taking reciprocals, where $S^{2}$ is considered as the one-point compactification of the complex plane.